# How do you register a python-based client with GCM (Google Cloud Messenger) to get a registration_id for the device?

Tags: python, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to figure out how to use one of the following python packages to create a python-based client that is capable of **receiving** XMPP-based messages via Google Cloud Messenging.

- https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm
- https://github.com/daftshady/py-gcm
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcm-client/
- https://github.com/pennersr/pulsus

From all I can see, ([e.g., the documentation for gcm-client](http://gcm-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)), these packages can send messages to other clients that are identified by `registration_id`. But how do I get a registration IDs for each client in the first place? In other words, how do I register the client-app that I am creating so that it can receive messages?

It is starting to seem to me that these are not clients per-se, but just libraries that can be used to push messages to clients. I hope that I am wrong about that and just missing a key concept.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: I did eventually figure it out, but I am sorry to say that I don't remember how, nor do I have the code around. It was involved. Sorry I can't be more help. Check out my response to the so_jin_ee below for a small hint, but you've probably already seen that...

Comment: Yea I saw that. But I don't wanna use java methods. and the link in the answer is expired. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Each client application has to call the `getRegistrationId()` to get the registration id once. Then they can receive messages. A more detailed function call is [**here**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

I hope this give you an idea on client devices. :)

Comment: Thanks, but none of the libraries I linked to above provide a way to call that function. I have resorted to using pyjnius to call the java methods (such as the one you mentioned).